# Azure AutoML Python SDK, Issues importing into VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a .yml that installs all the necessary Azure ML packages.
Upon creating the environment with the YML, I test to make sure I can import the packages, and I can.
But when I open the Jupyter notebook I will be using and import the necessary packages, one is not found.

```
from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.train.automl.automlconfig'

But When I import it in the command prompt, it successfully imports

[image]

It seems like this is an issue with VS code, has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Found a similar issue here: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the issue while importing AutoMLConfig in VSCode as below:

[image]

Followed the below steps to fix it by installing its related Python packages.

- Activate the virtual environment from below command

> ```
> python -m venv .venv
> .venv\Scripts\activate
> ```

- Then install pip install azureml and “pip install azureml-core”

> ```
> Pip install azureml-train
> Pip install azureml-train-automl
> ```

Also, we have a [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py) where we have all the sub packages of azureml.